# How to send invitations to join a group from stand alone IOS app

Tags: ios, imessage, messageui

I have a client who is requesting a feature that I'm not sure is possible as he describes it.  He would like to send an invitation to one or more of his contacts via a text message, all from with in his stand alone app.  That part would be fairly easy (I think).  When the contact receives the text message containing the invitation and taps on it, one of two things happen:

1) if the recipient doesn't have the stand alone app on his device, he is directed to the App Store to download it. When the app is first run the user is added to the group that he was invited to.  The app itself has UI that indicates that the user is a member of group .

2) If the user already had the app, he would simply be added to the group (if he accepts the invitation).I've looked into the Message and MessageUI frameworks.  I'm not seeing a way to accomplish this task exactly.  The text message would have to somehow contain data referencing the group info to be joined.  And then actually configure the stand alone app with that group info - even if that means waiting for the app to be downloaded from the App Store first.  Seems far fetched.

Does anyone have any pointers as to how this task may be accomplished?

Comment: There's nothing that can be done if the app has to be downloaded first (unless you access it twice from the message, once to download, once to configure). If the app already exists on the phone then it could be launched with a url containing some appended info about the group

Comment: If the App is on someones phone and it accesses their contacts, then you can check your database (presuming it contains users phone numebers) to see if they already have the app. If they dont have the app, create a temporary record in the database (using the phone number) and send them a Text with the Download URL of the App in Appstore.

Comment: Once they log in, (get their phone number), reference the temp record in the database and add them to a predefined group. You will want to age the temp file so that if they dont join within 7 days or something you delete the record

Comment: You can send along a code, so they can enter it to add to the group, if they already have the app, simply using push notification is better